# Duplicated results in EntityManager.getResultList()

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence, hql

When I send this HQL query to a MySQL ddbb

```
public List<EscaleCatalogueKaravel> obtenirListeEscalesCroisiereAvecIdCroisiereKaravel(Integer idCroisiereKaravel, Integer refLangue) {
         List<EscaleCatalogueKaravel> listeEscales = entityManager.createQuery("select p from EscaleCatalogueKaravel p " +
                    "where p.idCroisiereComplete=:idCroisiereComplete and p.refLangue=:refLangue")
                    .setParameter("idCroisiereComplete", idCroisiereKaravel)
                    .setParameter("refLangue", refLangue)
                    .getResultList();

         return listeEscales;
    }
```

I got the correct number of results, though all of them are the same. However if I query the ddbb manually (the query which is showed in the logs) the resultset is correct.

Also, if I substitute "p" for the field names in the Entity, the result is correct (but there are no property names in the results set, just indexes)

This is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="view_croisiereitineraire")
public class EscaleCatalogueKaravel implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name="idCroisiereComplete")
    private Integer idCroisiereComplete;

    @Column(name="idEscale")
    private Integer idEscale;

    @Column(name="nomEscale")
    private String nomEscale;

    @Column(name="refMarche")
    private Integer refMarche;

    @Column(name="refLangue")
    private Integer refLangue;



    public Integer getIdCroisiereComplete() {
        return idCroisiereComplete;
    }

    ,..


}
```

I'm doing exactly the same with other entities and everything works fine. Ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably because

```
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

should be added to your query, but this has been answered like a thousand times on this forum already